# Alpha Channel not encoding into Webm

Tags: rendering, transparency

I'm trying to get alpha transparency to display correctly in a webm format from a .png image sequence. Here is a sample of the image to show alpha is active there.

[image]

Here are the settings used to encode:

[image]

Here is the result. See how it renders as black and not pink, which as far as I know means there's no alpha.

[image]

Now I know these settings have worked in previous encodes just fine and am wondering if I'm just missing something obvious. Any solutions would be appreciated.